# Save Activity instance in a Fragment

Tags: android

`Fragment` has a method named `getActivity()` which returns the activity with which the fragment currently is associated.

Is it safe to not use this method, but instead save the `Activity` instance in the `onAttach(Activity)` method?

For example, change from:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public void foo() {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).foo();
    }
}
```

to:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivity activity;
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }
    public void foo() {
        this.activity.foo();
    }
}
```

Are there any differences between these two approaches? Which is better?

PS. One benefit of the second approach is that you don't have to do type conversion each time you use the activity (like `(MainActivity) getActivity()`). But I don't know whether it's safe to save the activity instance.

Comment: Same thing.  Holding a reference to the Activity in onAttach() is probably more elegant though, in case you want to communicate something back to the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's ok. I do that almost always to avoid calling method getActivity() and casting result every time (for better performance and better code)